# Jquery $(this) is not working inside on 'change' function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask why $(this) is not working inside my on change function?

My goal is to hide the input if the checkbox is clicked.

```js
$('#checkboxContactName').on('change', () => {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    console.log('is checked!');
    $(this).parent().next().css('display', 'none');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().next().css('display', 'block');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="#" title="Contact Name">Contact</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="float:right;"><input id="checkboxContactName" type="checkbox" /> Hide
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: change `() =>` to `function()`. try this.

Comment: You can use `event.target` within arrow function to reference element where event is dispatched

Comment: Change the () => to function() and close the tag as I did for you in the snippet I made for you. It would also be useful if you had a parent().next() in your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It will work. You need to change the arrow function to plain function

```
$('#checkboxContactName').on('change', function()  {
  if($(this).prop('checked')) {
    console.log('is checked!');
    $(this).parent().next().css('display', 'none');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().next().css('display', 'block');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the arrow function syntax to to function declaration or get the `event` parameter in the function and use `event.currentTarget` instead of `this`. You don't need to preserve outer context in the arrow function. The `this` must refer to that context which jQuery bound to it.

```js
$('#checkboxContactName').on('change', function() {
     if($(this).prop('checked')) {
         console.log('is checked!');
         $(this).parent().next().css('display', 'none');
     } else {
         $(this).parent().next().css('display', 'inline-block');
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="#" title="Contact Name">Contact</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" style="float:right;"  >
    <input id="checkboxContactName" type="checkbox"/> Hide
    </label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the arrow function, you can access the element like this :

```
$('#checkboxContactName').on('change', (ev) => {
   if(ev.target.checked) {
        console.log('is checked!');
    } else {
        console.log("unchecked")
    }
});
```